# Does strpos have an issue with a string that has html in it?

Tags: php

`strpos` is not finding `>$2.99<`. I have echoed `$html` right before the if statement, and I can find `>$2.99<` in it, but the result is `not found`.

```
$webpage = file_get_contents ($itunesurl);
$html = htmlspecialchars ($webpage); 
echo $html;


if(strpos($html, '>$2.99<') !== FALSE) {
    echo 'found';
}
else {
    echo 'not found';
    }
```

Comment: You're using `htmlspecialchars()`, which will convert `<` to `&lt;` and so on.

Comment: Remember that you're probably viewing that echo output in a browser, which will render the htmlspecialchar()-escaped data as the actual character. View the page source to see what the string REALLY looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search `$webpage` rather than `$html`, since the `>` and `<` characters get converted to entities by `htmlspecialchars`.

```
if(strpos($webpage, '>$2.99<') !== FALSE) {
    echo 'found';
}
else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Comment: Yep. That was it. I wrongly assumed that I needed to convert my string to html with htmlspecialchar. Thanks.